# Как из города получить координаты?

Tags: android, геолокация, location

Подскажите, как мне из города получить координаты. Это необходимо для того чтобы рассчитать расстояние с пункта А в пункт Б. Я это делаю примерно так:

```
 private void getLocation(){
    fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
       Location location = task.getResult();
       if(location!=null) {
           Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
           try {
               List<Address> adress = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
          tx1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#6200EE'><b>Latitude :</b><br></font>" +
                  adress.get(0).getLatitude()));
               tx2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#6200EE'><b>Longitude :</b><br></font>" +
                       adress.get(0).getLongitude()));
               tx3.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#6200EE'><b>Country Name :</b><br></font>" +
                       adress.get(0).getCountryName()));
               tx4.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#6200EE'><b>Locality :</b><br></font>" +
                       adress.get(0).getLocality()));
               tx5.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#6200EE'><b>Adres :</b><br></font>" +
                       adress.get(0).getAddressLine(0)));

               double lngA = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml("" +
                       adress.get(0).getLongitude())));

               double latA = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml("" +
                       adress.get(0).getLatitude())));

               Location locationA = new Location("point A");
               Location locationB = new Location("point B");
               Location locationC = new Location("point C");
               Location locationD = new Location("point D");

               locationA.setLatitude(latA);
               locationB.setLongitude(lngA);
               locationC.setLatitude(46.48253);
               locationD.setLongitude(30.72331);

               double distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationC) ;
               double distance2 = locationB.distanceTo(locationD) ;
               double distance3 = distance + distance2;

               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + distance3/1000 + " км", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }catch (IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
        }
    });
}
```

Может как то по другому можно узнать расстояние. Первый раз работаю с location.
Мне нужно чтобы я мог забить в строчку город или название населенного пункта и оно мне посчитало расстояние.

Comment: вопрос непонятен. Вон же координаты - lngA  и latA. И считаете вы как-то странно. Города у вас два, а локаций в коде - четыре. Причем метод distanceTo вы используете, а вот что он делает, видимо не знаете. Иначе не было бы этого вопроса.

Comment: Нет не знаю, вообще первый раз работаю с этим всем. Вот и задаю глупые вопросы ))). Вопрос вообще изначально в том, чтобы я мог вводить 2 разных города, и программа считала расстояние между ними.